# Why I get (sligtly) different outputs reading the same char* buffer using two different methods?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, bitset

I'm writing a program in C++ to read and decode data received over TCP which I store in a char* buffer. 
**Method 1** 
Since I found useful to be able to read the buffer for debugging purposes, I firstly used this function to extract a given number of bytes from the buffer:

```
string MyClass::extractBytes(int a, int b) {
    string s = "";
    for (int i = a; i <= b; ++i) {
        bitset<8> b(DATA[i]);
        s += b.to_string();
    }
    return std::string(s);
}
```

where DATA is the char* buffer (private MyClass object member). This way I also get the correct endianness and I'm able to read the binary values if needed. I have a *int* cursor I increment after each operation. This method showed result that matched the expected values received from the device
**Method 2** 
Performance is not that big of a deal in this project, but I would like to use a better approach here. I'm considering using a *char* pointer to run thru the buffer and get the values directly from there. Let's say I have to read a 32 bit value at index 30:

```
char* cursorPtr = DATA; //initializing the cursor to point the same memory address
cursorPtr += 30;
uint32_t value32 = *(reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(cursorPtr));
bitset<32> bitValue(swapEndianness(value32));


//SWAP FUNCTION
static uint32_t swapEndianness32(uint32_t value) {
    uint32_t result = 0;
    result |= (value & 0x000000FF) << 24;
    result |= (value & 0x0000FF00) << 8;
    result |= (value & 0x00FF0000) >> 8;
    result |= (value & 0xFF000000) >> 24;
    return result;
}
```

Now, if I'm going to print the output of those two methods  I got *almost always* the same results, but *sometimes* they differ somehow (for method one, I used *extractBytes(startPosition, endPosition)*). Example output:

```
STRING:  00010010000000000000111100000000 00001000000001001110111100000001
VALUE:   00010000000000000000100011110000 00001000000001001110111100000001

STRING:  00010101000000000001110000000000 00001000000001001110111100000001
VALUE:   00010101000000000001110100000000 00001000000001001110111100000001
```

I showed blocks of 64 bits to let you know that almost everything matches (and that *can't* be a coincidence) except for some values. At first I supposed to have messed something with the endianness thing, so I printed a single byte. Plus, I also addressed it differently to spot pointer increments issues:

```
s1 = extractBytes(cursor, cursor);
s2 = uint8_t value = *(reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&DATA[cursor])); //I know char is 8 bits
```

Still, the output *sometimes* is different. Another test I made was to use memcpy to extract the values from the buffer and save them to another location:

```
char MEM[8];
memcpy(MEM, &DATA[cursor], 8);
uint64_t value64 = *(reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(MEM));
log << swapEndianness64(value64);
```

But still the problems remains. What's the reason of this behaviour?

Comment: `cursorPtr += 30;` and then `uint32_t value32 = *(reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(cursorPtr));` looks like a potentially aliasing breaking cast.

Comment: Even when i address it directly? `uint32_t value32 = *(reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&DATA[cursor]));`?

Comment: Your method 2 is full of bad practices to the brim. `reinterpret_cast` here is UB so there's little sense in discussing it further. You don't need reiterpret_cast and you don't need to swap endianness. Just read bytes as 8-bit integers and stuff them into an uint32_t in the right order.

Comment: Something like `result = (DATA[i]<<24) | (DATA[i+1]<<16) | DATA[i+2]<<8 | DATA[i+3]`, and please use UNSIGNED CHAR for the love of God. The above statement compiles to a single `bswap` instruction. https://godbolt.org/z/BfwBy9

Comment: "_Even when I address it directly?_" - Yes. For the alignment alone you could create a function like [`aligned_ok()`](https://godbolt.org/z/8EkqwH). For communication purposes people often pack data tighter than the alignment allows and in that case you need to do as @n.'pronouns'm. suggest or `memcpy` from the `char*` into the _unsigned_ target (that obviously is aligned properly).

Comment: Thanks for the precious suggestions everyone.  @n. 'pronouns' m. how can I cast to unsigned char* avoiding UB? The function I use (from the STL) accepts a char* to fill the buffer. Something like `unsigned char *conbuf = (unsigned char *)buf;` can work in this case? Thank you.

Comment: You can cast between signed and unsigned char freely, it is a well-defined operation.

Comment: `bitset<8> b(DATA[i]);` -- You have a function argument named `b`, and naming something inside the loop `b` just make things confusing. Yes, it's legal, and its effect is well defined. Don't do it.

Comment: Thank you, I will remember that!